# vs code autocomplete other

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering how to get VS Code to autocomplete HTML tags in files that aren't `.html`

I'm working on a vue.js project which have a pages HTML, JavaScript, and CSS all in one file that have a `.vue` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the Vetur extension and you get emmet and auto completion out of the box.

> #### Features
>
> - Syntax-highlighting
> - Snippet
> - Emmet
> - Linting / Error Checking
> - Formatting
> - Auto Completion
> - Debugging

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur